# Integer overflow for looping over large vector in C?

Tags: c

We can use a for loop to iterate over a vector in C, for example:

```
int len = length(x);
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    double val = REAL(x)[i];
}
```

This seems to work fine, but I don' understand why. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) the default `int` type ranges from −32767 to +32767. So why does this still work for vectors longer than that?

Does R somehow override `int` to always be `long int`? Is there a maximum length of the vector that this code will support?

Comment: In addition to @NPE's answer, you might want to have a look at `.Machine` specifically `.Machine$integer.max`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta: Thanks for that. I've added `.Machine$integer.max` to my answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: the max int value depends on the architecture of the CPU.  For a 16 bit machine, the value is +2^15 to -2^15-1.  That is your +32768 to -32767.  for a 32 bit machine, the value is +2^31 to -2^31-1.

Comment: All 32 and 64-bit systems have int as 32 bits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are misreading Wikipedia. Here is a more complete [quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types) (emphasis mine):

> **At least** in the [−32767,+32767] range

On most modern platforms (at least those powerful enough to run R), `int` is at least 32 bits wide, which gives a range of `[−2147483647,+2147483647]` or more.

Additionally, R's `?integer` has the following to say:

> Note that current implementations of R use 32-bit integers for integer vectors, so the range of representable integers is restricted to about +/-2*10^9: doubles can hold much larger integers exactly.

Finally, `?.Machine` say:

> `integer.max` - the largest integer which can be represented. Always 2147483647.

Comment: Thanks! I was already aware of the latter part (about R always using `long int` for its integer vectors) but I don't think that directly relates to the size of the standard `int` type in C?

Comment: @Jeroen: I think it's better to not conflate them into the same type, since the two languages provide different guarantees about the range.